# Using coldfusion data in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, variables, coldfusion, coldfusion-10

In the code I am writing I have a table I am prepopulating with names of children that I am getting from a table in MYSQL. In the table, some of the questions have other questions in divs appear depending on the answers. However, since there are an unknown number of children in the table, I am trying to use the childIDs in order to give each coldfusion id a unique id. The code for that is as follows:

```
    <cfinput type="radio" name="abuseNone#childID#" id="abuseNoneYes#childID#" value=1
        onClick="setAbuseVisible(checked); setAbuseDisable(!checked);"/>
    <label for="abuseNoneYes#childID#">Y</label>
    <cfinput type="radio" name="abuseNone#childID#" id="abuseNoneNo#childID#" value=0
        onClick="setAbuseVisible(!checked); setAbuseDisable(checked); setOtherVisible(!checked);"/>
    <label for="abuseNoneNo#childID#">N</label>
    <br>
<div id="abuseType#childID#" style= "padding: 5px 0 0 10px;">
    <cfinput type="checkbox" name="abuseNeglect#childID#" id="abuseNeglect#childID#" value=1/>Neglect
    <br>
    <cfinput type="checkbox" name="abusePhysAbuse#childID#" id="abusePhysAbuse#childID#" value=1/>Physical Abuse
    <br>
    <cfinput type="checkbox" name="abuseSexAbuse#childID#" id="abuseSexAbuse#childID#" value=1/>Sexual Abuse
    <br>
    <cfinput type="checkbox" name="abuseEmoAbuse#childID#" id="abuseEmoAbuse#childID#" value=1/>Emotional Abuse
    <br>
    <cfinput type="checkbox" name="abuseOther#childID#" id="abuseOther#childID#" value=1 onClick="setOtherVisible(checked);"/>Other
</div>
<br>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    setAbuseVisible(document.getElementById("abuseNoneYes" + "jsVar").checked);
</script>
<div id="abuseText" style= "padding: 5px 0 0 20px;">
    <cfinput type="text" style="width:120px" name="abuseOtherText#childID#" id="abuseOtherText#childID#" maxlength="140"/>
</div>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    setOtherVisible(document.getElementById("abuseOther" + "jsVar").checked);
</script>
```

I tried to make my childID into something I could use in javascript by this:

```
    <cfset thisString=#childID#>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
        <cfoutput>
            var #toScript(thisString, "jsVar")#;
        </cfoutput>
    </script>
```

My javascript functions were then as follows:

```
    function setAbuseDisable(checked)
        {
            document.getElementById("abuseNeglect" + "jsVar").disabled = checked;
            document.getElementById("abusePhysAbuse" + "jsVar").disabled = checked;
            document.getElementById("abuseSexAbuse" + "jsVar").disabled = checked;
            document.getElementById("abuseEmoAbuse" + "jsVar").disabled = checked;
            document.getElementById("abuseOther" + "jsVar").disabled = checked;
            document.getElementById("abuseOtherText" + "jsVar").disabled = checked;
        }

        function setAbuseVisible(abuseNone" + "jsVar")
        {
            if (abuseNone" + "jsVar")
            {
                document.getElementById("abuseType" + "jsVar").style.visibility = "visible";
                document.getElementById("abuseType" + "jsVar").style.height = "70px";
            }
            else
            {
                document.getElementById("abuseType" + "jsVar").style.visibility = "hidden";
                document.getElementById("abuseType" + "jsVar").style.height = "2px";
                document.getElementById("abuseNeglect" + "jsVar").checked = false;
                document.getElementById("abusePhysAbuse" + "jsVar").checked = false;
                document.getElementById("abuseSexAbuse" + "jsVar").checked = false;
                document.getElementById("abuseEmoAbuse" + "jsVar").checked = false;
                document.getElementById("abuseOther" + "jsVar").checked = false;
                document.getElementById("abuseOtherText" + "jsVar").checked = false;
                return false;
            }
```

I know it is setting the variable correctly, but I think I might be utilizing it incorrectly...If anyone has any advice on what I am doing wrong I would really appreciate it.

Comment: What is the code *supposed* to be doing (in plain english)? For example *"I have two radio buttons and five checkboxes. When radio button `X` is checked, I want to hide {this field} "* -or- *" make {these} checkbox elements 'checked' "*

Comment: @Leigh, I have an unknown number of children that appear in a table, and I'm using ID numbers to tell them apart. There are questions that have to be asked for each child in the table, and some of them need to appear based on other answers. To do that, I am trying to use the IDs (called childID) at the end of the variable names in order to distinguish which child to make the question appear for.

Comment: The first question I want to appear is in the div "abuseType", depending on if the radio button abuseNoneYes is checked. the second is in div "abuseText", depending on if the "other" checkbox is selected.

Comment: Yes, I understand the items are linked by `#childID#`. However, the overall goal is still a bit murky. It seems like the `<div>` contains options related to *one* of the two radio buttons. Are you simply trying to hide/show the `<div>` container (and un-check all boxes), when the "Y" button is selected? Does the form contain other elements with the same structure (radio + div + checkboxes)? You might want to look into using jQuery for this, rather than rolling your own js.